# Insert an input in a div with class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I want to add an HTML input to this div:

```
<div class="sss" style="padding-top:2px"> 
<center> 
 <input value="test1" name="name1" type="submit" >  
<input value="test2" name="name2" type="submit">
  </center> 
</div>
```

I used this:

```
$(".sss").append('<input  onclick =loc(); value="test3" >');
```

It's working, but I want to add it between `<center>` tag.
I used this code but it doesn't work and add it's after `</center>` tag.

```
$(".sss:first").append('<input  onclick =loc(); value="test3" >');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".sss center").append('<input  onclick =loc(); value="test3" >');
```

---

to put it in between input tags

```
$(".sss center :first-child").after('<input  onclick =loc(); value="test3" >');
// or $(".sss center :first").after('<input  onclick =loc(); value="test3" >');
// or $(".sss center :last-child").before('<input  onclick =loc(); value="test3" >');
```

Comment: ad now how can i put it between input tags?